Should [translation] be a synonym of [language-translation] or vice versa?
Isn't any form of translation from one language to another, regardless if its a human language or a machines language? Also the language machines use is created by humans therefore you could argue it is some form of human language itself. Why differentiate then?
Why are there two tags with very similar description?
from translation tag:
"Translation is the process of replacing strings in an application or website to make interfacing with the application or website easier for people from countries with different languages."
from language-translation tag:
"Translation from one human language to another in coding that ultimately determines the language viewed and used by the user."

There also exists the concept of translation in mathematics. Not sure though whether there are questions explicitly talking about this and using the translation tag.

Neither of these tags seem to be about converting code from one programming language into another.
You are probably thinking about code-translation.
That being said, these two tags (translation and language-translation) should probably be synonyms.
On the other hand, code-translation shouldn't.

You're correct, though notably there are questions misusing both of those tags to refer to something along the lines of code translation (example tagged language-translation, example tagged translation).  That probably needs a cleanup in addition to this.

"Translation" in the context of a program's operation can mean what e.g. Python's translate method on strings does. I don't think that merits a tag at all, but it seems worth checking for questions about that method getting mis-tagged. As for "code translation", is that ever actually in scope?

"is that ever actually in scope?" Probably. I don't think it needs an entire tag, though. It can be in scope as something like "I have algorithm in  I am trying to write it in  but can't seem to find how to do  - what can I use in ?"
